# MSO tag [20k] is the same as [trusted-user]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, synonym-request, trusted-user

Meta Stack Overflow tag [20k](/questions/tagged/20k) (9 questions as of now) looks the same as [trusted-user](/questions/tagged/trusted-user) (14 questions as of now), consider making these synonyms.

---

For the record, *20k* has no tag wiki, *trusted-user* has tag wiki and excerpt, latter says

> They of the 20000 reputation...

As for tag names, *trusted-user* sounds more informative than *20k* (which doesn't look bad to me either).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

20k now maps to [trusted-user](/questions/tagged/trusted-user), the more informative, descriptive of the two.